# MS SQL loop through all DBs. Script works to alter table but not stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use a piece of code to loop through all the databases on an MS SQL server.  It works fine for altering a column on a table and also for updating the data.  But I continue to get errors when trying to alter a stored procedure.  Here is the code:

```
use master

declare @dbname varchar(100)
,@sql varchar(max)

declare db_cur cursor for
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases where ([name] like 'ce%')
and [state] = 0   

open db_cur
fetch next from db_cur into @dbname

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

set @sql=
'ALTER TABLE ['+@dbname+'].[dbo].MyStuff
ADD myNewColumn bit NULL DEFAULT(0)
'

exec(@sql)

fetch next from db_cur into @dbname

end

close db_cur
deallocate db_cur
```

So the code above works perfectly fine.  But when I alter that code to instead do an alter stored procedure I receive the message below:

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

I realized that the message stated I can't use the database name in the front of the procedure like I was doing here:  ALTER procedure ['+@dbname+'].[dbo].[spSelectSomething].  But I haven't been able to figure out a way around the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thinking out loud, maybe add 'USE '+@dbname+'; ' to the SQL being run so it puts itself in the correct database before altering the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest dynamic SQL for this task because a proc `CREATE` or `ALTER` must be the first statement in the batch:

```
SET @sql= N'EXEC(N''USE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N';EXEC(N''''CREATE PROC...;'''')'')';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DanGuzman I need to do something like this but `ALTER` a stored procedure.  However, I can't seem to get my escape sequences right for the varchar strings within the code of the SP.  For the code within the `ALTER PROC....;` statement, how `'` are needed to escape a string? Thank you.

Comment: @RLH, each quote within your `ALTER PROC` statement text needs to be escaped with 8 quotes due to the multiple nesting levels. I suggest you search/replace the quotes in your original ALTER PROC code in a separate query window, copy the result to the clipboard, and paste it over the `CREATE PROC...;` code in my answer. The code will be ugly.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman I posted my question early in the morning after very long and late night of coding, but I did figure this out.  You are correct-- this code is ugly with all of the `''''''''...''''''''` strings, but it worked perfectly.  +1 for the assistance and the solution.